# Neo4j 3+ logging customization

Tags: neo4j

Is there any way to customize logging on Neo4j 3+? Something like logback.xml where I can define log pattern, output files, levels, rolling policy and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about using Neo4j Server, then the logging configuration is available in the `neo4j.conf` file, with options prefixed by `dbms.logs.`: https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/

These options include log level, output files, rotation policy, etc.

If you're using Neo4j embedded in another application (which you probably shouldn't), then you can use the [`setUserLogProvider(...)`](http://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/javadocs/org/neo4j/graphdb/factory/GraphDatabaseFactory.html#setUserLogProvider-org.neo4j.logging.LogProvider-) of the `GraphDatabaseFactory`. If you want to route user logging to another framework, there is a `Slf4jLogProvider` in the neo4j-logging jar, which can be used to send logs to slf4j and onto wherever you like.

Comment: If I use Neo4j Server is it only one way for the logging configuration (using `neo4j.conf` properties)?
Or maybe it is possible to customize logging framework (similar to `setUserLogProvider`)?

Comment: Neo4j Server is a standalone application, which provides configuration via `neo4j.conf`. I'm not aware of any options that can be specified in this configuration to change the logging framework.

Comment: I'm not sure what your use case is, but I'd probably just let Neo4j server write the logs to file, then parse those for whatever your additional needs are.

Comment: What was the reason for removing custom-logback.xml and another configs for logger customization?

Comment: To remove the dependency on external logging frameworks, allowing embedded deployments of neo4j to avoid conflict with the application's logging framework selection, and support the use of whatever logging framework they prefer (by providing a `LogProvider` adaptor).

Comment: Also note that the use of logback inside Neo4j was removed several years ago, since somewhere in the 2.x release series.